# Join ruins the select

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables that contains People who are working at the company and their Employment information (so People is one table, Employment is another).
The People table contains information on where the person lives, emergency contact, phone number bla bla bla. The Employment table contains information on where he works, closest boss and more.
These tables have been corrupted and now contains a few duplicates by misstake. Now in both tables there is a Person id, but the employment id is only located in Employment. I want both numbers on all people that have been duplicated.

This works perfectly:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    pp.Personid,
    pp.Firstname,
    pp.Lastname,
    pp.Address,
FROM People pp
JOIN People pp2
    ON pp.Firstname = pp2.Firstname
    AND pp.Lastname = pp2.Lastname
    AND pp.Address = pp2.Address
    AND pp.Personid <> pp2.Personid
ORDER BY pp.Firstname, pp.Lastname, pp.Personid
```

returning the following values (but does not include Employment number as you can see):

```
1001    Carl    Johnsson    Bigstreet 1
1002    Carl    Johnsson    Bigstreet 1
1003    Carl    Johnsson    Bigstreet 1
1010    Andrew  Wilkinsson  Smallstreet 2
1011    Andrew  Wilkinsson  Smallstreet 2
```

Now, to add the employment id I join in that table like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    pp.Personid,
    e.Employmentid,
    pp.Firstname,
    pp.Lastname,
    pp.Address,
FROM People pp
JOIN People pp2
    ON pp.Firstname = pp2.Firstname
    AND pp.Lastname = pp2.Lastname
    AND pp.Address = pp2.Address
    AND pp.Personid <> pp2.Personid
JOIN Employment e on pp.Personid = e.Personid
ORDER BY pp.Firstname, pp.Lastname, pp.Personid
```

And everything goes to h**l in a handbasket with the following result:

```
1001    1111    Carl    Johnsson    Bigstreet 1
1001    1111    Carl    Johnsson    Bigstreet 1
1001    1111    Carl    Johnsson    Bigstreet 1
1010    1234    Andrew  Wilkinsson  Smallstreet 2
1010    1234    Andrew  Wilkinsson  Smallstreet 2
```

As you can see I get both Personid and Employmentid but now I only get one of each (repeated the correct number of times) so I don't have all the different Personid and Employmentid in my list.

Why?

What happened with my join that crashed the party?

Comment: What SQL dialect/RDBMS?

Comment: This is written in MS SQL on MS SQL server 2012.

Comment: Have you checked if one `Person` can be `employed` multiple times?

Comment: A person that is duplicated will also be duplicated in employed, that is true, but since I join employed on Personid, how can the personid become the same one 3 times (for Carl in my example)?? It seems to me that it should either be 3 different or the 3 different times the amount of employments that exists in the employee table. But getting the exact correct amount of rows but with the same info seems very strange in my book.

Comment: It may be a nonsense, but I don't see your tables and don't know how much has the data been corrupted - if you perform `select * from ...` with the Employment table joined, plus, order it by the `PersonId`, not the names, don't you see anything suspicious?

Comment: can you the show the data in employment table?

Comment: It might be a good idea to run DBCC CHECKDB on your database and make sure it's not corrupt.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176064.aspx

Comment: I apologize for using the word "corrupt", what I meant is that the scripts that enter data into the tables had a bug in it which resulted in duplicates.

Comment: Can you post the data for those 5 people in both the People and Employment tables? It appears that you have duplicates of some People in the Employment table (e.g. I suspect that 1001 appears 3 times in employment table). Agree that its odd that the data set is the same size in both cases, but that looks like a data problem. We need to see the source data to be able to answer with certainty.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's make some sample data;

```
CREATE TABLE #People (PersonID int, FirstName varchar(50), LastName varchar(50), Address1 varchar(50))

INSERT INTO #People (PersonID, FirstName, LastName, Address1)
VALUES
('1','Mike','Hunt','Cockburn Crescent')
,('2','Mike','Hunt','Cockburn Crescent')
,('3','Mike','Hunt','Cockburn Crescent')
,('4','Connie','Lingus','Dyke Close')
,('5','Connie','Lingus','Dyke Close')
,('6','Eric','Shun','Tickle Avenue')
,('7','Ivana','Humpalot','Bottom Street')

CREATE TABLE #Employment (PersonID int, EmploymentID int)

INSERT INTO #Employment (PersonID, EmploymentID)
VALUES
('1','10')
,('2','11')
,('3','12')
,('4','13')
,('5','14')
,('6','15')
,('7','16')
```

I'd do the first query differently, if you work out the duplicates in a sub-select it would be easier, you'll then be able to join to the employment table with no problems;

```
SELECT pp.PersonID
    ,em.EmploymentID
    ,pp.FirstName
    ,pp.LastName
    ,pp.Address1
FROM #People pp
JOIN (
    SELECT FirstName
        ,LastName
        ,Address1
        ,COUNT(1) records
    FROM #People
    GROUP BY FirstName
        ,LastName
        ,Address1
    HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
    ) pp2 ON pp.FirstName = pp2.FirstName
    AND pp.LastName = pp2.LastName
    AND pp.Address1 = pp2.Address1
LEFT JOIN #Employment em ON pp.PersonID = em.PersonID
```

Remember to clean up the temp tables;

```
DROP TABLE #People
DROP TABLE #Employment
```

Comment: This solved my problem thanks a lot! Still a bit curious as to why my version didn't work...

Comment: Ok, update the question with the data for a user that is not showing as you expect. Show us all columns in People and all columns in Employment with the data for the one user. We'll be able to work it out from there.

Comment: Tempted to give this a +1 just for the imaginative names!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT
          ep.Personid,
          ep.Employementid,
          ep.FirstName,
          ep.LastName,
          ep.Address
FROM Person P join
(SELECT 
    pp.Personid,
    e.Employmentid,
    pp.Firstname,
    pp.Lastname,
    pp.Address,
from PP
JOIN Employment e on pp.Personid = e.Personid ) ep
on 
    P.Firstname = ep.Firstname
    AND P.Lastname = ep.Lastname
    AND P.Address = ep.Address
    AND P.Personid <> ep.Personid
ORDER BY P.Firstname, P.Lastname, P.Personid
```

Sir please Check and reply to me

Comment: This generat es the same problem as my own second table, i.e the Personid repeats without changing.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work and I am unable to reproduce your issue using data I have made up. The outcome you are seeing suggests to me that there are multiple person id's for carl johnsson in the employment table and that the employmentid is different - even though it looks the same in the output.
Can you supply your table definitions and sample data?